# Change language of selected text in Powerpoint VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I need to change the language of selected text in Powerpoint 2019 to US English using Macro.

I tried below Macro but it does nothing: Any help?

```
Sub English()

'ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.LanguageID = msoLanguageIDUSEnglish

End Sub
```

Comment: If you don't remove the apostrophe `'` in the beginning of the line it is just a comment and will not do anything.

Comment: Thanks, I removed it but I got error

Comment: Well without you [edit]ing your question and adding an error description no one here will be able to help.

Comment: `msoLanguageIDUSEnglish` doesn't seem to be a valid value for `LanguageID`   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.textrange.languageid

Comment: Remove the ' so it's not a comment and use msoLanguageIDEnglishUS 
Hint: When in doubt, erase everything to the left of the = sign, then start typing from = again. If the rest of your code is correct, IntelliSense will pop up a list of the values available to you.  Or press F2 to get the Object Browser, where you can look up the correct values.